# Integration of Closed Curve: What is the difference between $\gamma_- $ and $\gamma'_{-}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-number-theory, curves

Let us define a curve $\gamma$ (orientated counterclockwise) as the boundary
of the region $\{s \in \mathbb C : |s| ≤ R, \sigma > -\delta\}$ where $s=\sigma+it$.

$\gamma_- = \gamma \cap  \{σ < 0\}$.

$\gamma'_{-} = \{|s| = R, σ < 0\}$ (a semicircle)

What is the difference between $\gamma_- $ and $\gamma'_{-}$? Is $\gamma_- = \gamma'_{-}$? If so, why is $\gamma_- = \gamma'_{-}$?

The source of confusion [is this M.Sc. thesis (go to page 113, 115)](http://mural.maynoothuniversity.ie/4470/1/finaldraftmsc.pdf). I am trying to understand the equation obtained by integration of closed path of $\gamma_- $ and $\gamma'_{-}$ respectively, I could not understand why the equation is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The curves $\gamma_-$ and $\gamma'_-$ are not the same. See the picture on p.113: $\gamma_-$ is the part of $\gamma$ in the closed half-plane $\text{Im}(z) \le 0$, and $\gamma'_-$ is the half circle with center $0$ and radius $R$ in this half-plane. But note that the curves agree on two small parts at their beginning at $-R$ and at their end at $R$ (both points are on the real axis):

However, the author only claims that the integrals over these two curves agree. This is true because the difference of the intergrals is an integral over a closed curve completetely contained in the open half-plane $\text{Im}(z) < 0$. We integrate a function which is holomorphic on the open half-plane, thus the integral is $0$.

**Edited:**

The claim is $\int_{\gamma_-} = \int_{\gamma'_-}$. This is the same as  $\int_{\gamma_- - \gamma'_-} = \int_{\gamma_-} - \int_{\gamma'_-} = 0$. Here $\varphi = \gamma_- - \gamma'_-$ is the closed curve obtained by going with  $\gamma_-$ from $-R$ to $R$ and with $-\gamma'_-$ (which is the path in opposite direction) from $R$ to $-R$. By Theorem 2.5.3 you see that $\int_\varphi = 0$ because $g_T(s)e^{sT}(1 +s^2/R^2)$ is an entire function.

Comment: Might be a silly question, but is $\gamma'_-$ included in the closed half-plane $\gamma_-$?

Comment: Both $\gamma_-$ and $\gamma'_-$ are contained in the closed half-plane $\text{Im}(z) \le 0$. $\gamma_-$ is contained in the closed half-disk bounded by $\gamma'_-$. Drawing a picture is helpful.

Comment: Ah.. thanks for the reply,though I am having some trouble to understand "But note that the curves agree on two small parts at their beginning at $-1$ and at their end at $1$".. which beginning at $-1$ and at their end at $1$?

Comment: Both curves start at $-1$ and run on the lower half unit circle until they reach the point $-\sqrt{1 - \delta^2} - i\delta$. The first curve continues on a horizontal line to the right, the second continues on the lower half unit circle until they meet again at $\sqrt{1 - \delta^2} - i\delta$. Then both go on the lower half unit circle until they reach $1$. You see that they agree at small parts close to $-1$ and $1$.

Comment: Still not clear... I mean which 1, -1 in which axis? ... I will try to draw a picture, but if possible plz provide a picture.. you can copy the picture on page 113 and edit it to show... if possible plz do that, many thanks for your answer, I upvoted and selected your answer, good day.

Comment: You can use this picture :   https://i.stack.imgur.com/ni1No.jpg

Comment: Ah, sorry, I missed that the circle has radius $R$. I edited my answer, In the comments you should replace $1$ by $R$.

Comment: u said " the difference of the integrals is an integral over a closed curve " .. should it be difference or sum? Should not it be a sum since the simple closed curve is created by joining those two curves ?

Comment: See my above edit.

Comment: Thanks, Paul but I am just not clear why  $\gamma'_-$ become $-\gamma'_-$ in the closed curve?

The path of $\gamma'_-$ is already defined in the opposite direction from $R$ to $−R$, since in $\gamma'_-$, $\sigma<0$. could you plz clear this point?

Comment: The author does not say it explicitly, but the curve $\gamma'_-$ is orientated counterclockwise (as the curve $\gamma$ which is introduced on p.113). Thus it goes from $-R$ to $R$ as $\gamma_-$. The inverse path is $-\gamma'_-$ which goes from $R$ to $-R$ along the lower half-circle. Composing $\gamma'_-$ and $-\gamma'_-$ gives the closed path $\varphi$. The condition $\sigma < 0$ doesn't say anything about the orientation of $-\gamma'_-$, it only says that it is contained in the lower half-plane.

Comment: Hi Andrew, your new question is about the Riemann zeta function, and I don't know very much about it. Thus, I am sorry, but it would cost me too much time and effort to fill all my gaps.